# mmenu - how to switch off auto open on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

Every time I load a page using mmenu the menu automaticaly appears after a second. How do I switch this off? I want the menu to appear ONLY after clicking on the menu button.

This is a link to the plugin: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

If the URL contains a hash that points to the menu, the menu will open. This is so the menu will open even if the user clicks the button before the menu was created. If you remove the hash from the URL, the menu will not open on pageload.